# How to create a new pandas column by scanning cross multiple columns using for-loops?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, filter

I have 25 variables DXCODE1 to DXCODE25, which I want to scan across to see if any of these values for each row matches the icd_list. For example, in each row, I want to scan across from DXCODE1 to DXCODE25 and see if any of these contains any one of the following three values: 'F32', 'F33', 'F34', if it does, then I want to return 1. I tried the following:

```
def scan_icd (row):
    icd_list = ['F32', 'F33', 'F34']
    for i in range(1, 26):
        dx_code_loc = 'DXCODE' + str(i)
        for j in range(0, len(icd_list)):
            if icd_list[j] in row[dx_code_loc]:
                return 1

df['ICD_DX'] = df.apply(scan_icd, axis=1)
```

But I got this error:

```
TypeError: ("argument of type 'float' is not iterable", 'occurred at index 1')
```

Also I would like to make it flexible so I can somehow specify the icd code as a list in the parameter. But I don't know how to apply syntax-wise:

```
def scan_icd (row, icd_list):
    icd_list = icd_list
    for i in range(1, 26):
        dx_code_loc = 'DXCODE' + str(i)
        for j in range(0, len(icd_list)):
            if icd_list[j] in row[dx_code_loc]:
                return 1

df['ICD_DX'] = df.apply(scan_icd (['F32', 'F33', 'F34']), axis=1)

TypeError: apply() got multiple values for argument 'axis'
```

===================

Edit:

The columns are labeled DXCODE1,DXCODE2, ... DXCODE25

Comment: Is each column labeled DXCODE1, DXCODE2, ... and so on?

Comment: Yes, I have added as edits above.

Comment: Ok, so to clarify, you want to see which rows contain an icd_code in any of the 25 columns?

Comment: I want to see which rows contains at least one of the designated icd codes in any of the 25 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this `apply` will do the job you want

```
icd_list = ['F32', 'F33', 'F34']
df['ICD_DX'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row.isin(icd_list).any() else 0, axis=1)
```

You check if any element of `icd_list` is in your `row`

EDIT: if you want to keep your for-loops (sorry I didn't see this requirement at first) I would do:

```
def scan_icd (row, icd_list):
    for i in range(1, 26):
        dx_code_loc = 'DXCODE' + str(i)
        for j in range(0, len(icd_list)):
            if icd_list[j] in row[dx_code_loc]:
                return 1
    return 0 # return 0 if none match
icd_list = ['F32', 'F33', 'F34']
df['ICD_DX'] = df.apply(scan_icd, args=([icd_list]), axis=1) 
# note the list of the list icd_list in args
```

EDIT 2: to specify the columns, you can do:

```
list_col = ['DXCODE' + str(i) for i in range(1,26)]
df['ICD_DX'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row[list_col].isin(icd_list).any() else 0, axis=1)
# see the difference is with row[list_col]
```

Comment: Any way to specify scanning just those 25 columns?

Comment: Thanks, I am trying the codes with loops. I am getting the same error - TypeError: ("argument of type 'float' is not iterable", 'occurred at index 1')

Comment: without your input data I'm not sure I can help, I created my own df and it works for me. I guess the error happens at the line `if icd_list[j] in row[dx_code_loc]`. Do you get the same error with `apply`?

Comment: Your Edit 2 code works, but sorry the reason why I prefer Edit (if working) was because it returns 1 as long as there is for example 'F32' is contained in the text, so things like 'F32', 'F32.1' and 'F32343' will return 1. Could you please guide me how to include this "regex" concept in your edit 2?

Comment: ok, replace `row[list_col].isin(icd_list).any()` by `row[list_col].str.contains('|'.join(icd_list)).any()` in my EDIT 2, it should do the job